# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2} f(x-2) \ dx$ knowing that $\int_{-2}^{0} f(x) \ dx = 3$ (possible textbook error)

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I am asked the following:

> Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2} f(x-2) \ dx$ knowing that $\int_{-2}^{0} f(x) \ dx = 3$

When I try to make a u-substitution I get

$$
u=x-2\\
du = dx\\
\\
\text{when } x = -2 \Rightarrow u = -4\\
\text{when } x = 0 \Rightarrow u = -2
$$

which leads me nowhere. Is there a typing error on the exercise? Would it make more sense if the original question was the following?

> Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2} f(x+2) \ dx$ knowing that $\int_{-2}^{0} f(x) \ dx = 3$

in which we would have

$$
u=x+2\\
du = dx\\
\\
\text{when } x = -2 \Rightarrow u = 0\\
\text{when } x = 0 \Rightarrow u = 2
$$

so that

$$\int_{0}^{2} f(x+2) \ dx = \int_{-2}^{0} f(x) \ dx = 3$$

Thank you.

Comment: Think graphically: $f(x-2)$ shifts $f$ two to the right

Comment: You chose the correct substitution, but then you apply the incorrect boundaries. Use the limits of integration from the first integration. Don't apply the second integral until after you've completed the substitution.

Comment: Yes zahbaz that's exactly what I did, thank you for explaining that. Best Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subsitution $u=x-2$ doesn't lead you no where, it gives you your answer! With this substitution, your bounds are $-2\leq u \leq 0$ and you get
$$
\int_0^2f(x-2)\,dx=\int_{-2}^0 f(u)\,du=\int_{-2}^0f(x)\,dx=3
$$
The variable of integration is just a dummy variable, it is irrelevant.

Comment: Ah I see my mistake: instead of substituting $0$ and $2$ I did it with $-2$ and $0$, which is incorrect. Thank you @qbert.

Comment: No problem! It may help to solve for $u$ and plug in the original bounds for $x$